# Calling a .srt file to an embed video code

Tags: video, embed

I am using this code

```
<embed style="text-align:center; padding-bottom: 20px;"

src="https://myschool.edu/webapps/portal/swfplayer/player.swf" 

height="197" 
width="350" 
allowscriptaccess="always" 
allowfullscreen="true" 

flashvars="&bandwidth=146429&file=videopath.mp4&streamer=rtmp://videoserver.myschool.edu/vod/&image=imgpath"

/>
```

and

I want to add a .srt file to this video. However, I don't have access to the server that has the player to add the caption plugin.  Is there a workaround that I can use with this code?